# Is the kernel of a matrix its nullspace and nothing more? And what is the term for the dimension of a kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Are null space and kernel perfect synonyms? If so, why are there two different terms for them?

Also, does the term "nullity" have a "kernel" equivalent? Nullity refers to the dimension of the null space (and thus dimension of the kernel), and seems very important, so is there another term I should be aware of that refers to nullity?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Different people just prefer different terms. To be honest, I just use these two terms interchangeably, depending on which one I feel like using at the moment.

Comment: In my experience:  the word "nullspace" is mostly used in undergraduate linear algebra courses, and "kernel" is used in more advanced courses.  Don't ask me why...

Comment: @JairTaylor I would suspect that this follows from the fact that "null space" is used mostly in linear algebra (which is typically a lower-division undergraduate course) and that "kernel" is used more generally in the study of groups, rings, fields, and other more general algebraic structures (which are typically the subject of more advanced courses).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that "kernel" and "null space" mean almost exactly the same thing, and you will likely never cause confusion by using the two terms interchangeably.

That being said, there are are some nuances, and I would not say that the two terms are "perfect synonyms".  In my experience, "kernel" is a more general term than "null space".  The term "kernel" is used to refer to a set in the domain of a homomorphism, where the homomorphism could be of any type; while the term "null space" refers specifically to a set in the domain of a linear transformation between vector spaces (a vector space homomorphism).

This seems to be consistent with a quick check of reliable sources on the internet.  For example, if we examine the definitions on MathWorld, we find:

> **Definition:** For any function $f:A\to B$ (where $A$ and $B$ are any sets), the [*kernel*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kernel.html) (also called the null space) is defined by
>   $$\ker(f) = \{x : x\in A\text{ such that }f(x) = 0\}.$$
>
> **Definition:** If $T$ is a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the [*null space*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullSpace.html) $\operatorname{Null}(T)$, also called the kernel, is the set of all vectors $\mathbf{X}$ such that
>   $$T(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{0}. $$

Per these definitions, the kernel and null space are exactly the same thing, though I would note that the definition of the null space refers only to linear transformations on real vector spaces, while the definition of the kernel applies to maps between any two sets (though, presumably, $B$ must contain some kind of zero element).

Wikipedia gives more detailed definitions.  Taking a somewhat general approach from the page [kernel (algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)), we have

> **Definition:**  Let $A$ and $B$ be algebraic structures of a given type and let $f$ be a homomorphism of that type from $A$ to $B$. Then the [*kernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)#General_case) of $f$ is the subset of the direct product $A \times A$ consisting of all those ordered pairs of elements of $A$ whose components are both mapped by $f$ to the same element in $B$. The kernel is usually denoted $\ker f$ (or a variation). In symbols:
>   $$\ker f=\{(a,a')\in A\times A:f(a)=f(a')\}. $$

In the cases where elements of $B$ have inverses, we have
$$ f(a) = f(a') \implies 1_B = -f(a) + f(a') = f(-a+a'), $$
where $+$ denotes the appropriate operation in $A$ or $B$ (depending on context), $1_B$ is the identity element in $B$ (note that $\mathbf{0}$ is the usual notation for the identity element in a vector space), and the last equality follows from properties of homomorphisms.

Wikipedia also gives the definition of a null space, under the heading [kernel (linear algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)):

> **Definition:** in linear algebra and functional analysis, the *kernel* (also known as *null space* or *nullspace*) of a linear map $L : V \to W$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, is the set of all elements $v$ of $V$ for which $L(v) = 0$, where 0 denotes the zero vector in $W$. That is, in set-builder notation,
>   $$\ker(L)=\{\mathbf {v} \in V\mid L(\mathbf {v} )=\mathbf {0} \}. $$

Per these definitions, the kernel and null space are *not* quite the same thing.  In particular, the term null space applies only to linear transformations between vector spaces, while the term kernel is much more general.

Generally speaking, you will likely not encounter the term "null space" except in the context of linear maps between vector spaces.  However, you would never be misunderstood if you called it the "kernel" of that map, instead.  On the other hand, if you were to refer to the "null space" of a group homomorphism, you might get a raised eyebrow or two.  In that context, you are probably better off using the term "kernel".

---

Regarding your question about the existence of an equivalent term to "nullity," I don't know the answer, though I suspect that it is "No."

When working with vector spaces, the dimension of those vector spaces are both important and relatively simple to define and determine.  The rank-nullity theorem relates the dimensions of the image and the null space, hence it is useful to have a term like "nullity" to abbreviate and simplify communication.

On the other hand, when working with more general algebraic structures, the notion of "dimension" is a lot more subtle, and does not necessarily work as you would like.  For example, I am not aware of a general version of the rank-nullity theorem which can be applied to module homomorphisms (though I suspect that some weak generalization might exist?), let alone group homomorphisms.  Since the "dimension" of the kernel of an arbitrary homomorphism may not even be defined, I suspect that there is no generally used term for the dimension of the kernel of a map.

Comment: More generaly there is also the purely categorical definition of the kernel of a morphism in a category with a zero object in terms of a universal property.

Comment: Also I think in general there is no version of rank-nullity for modules, because there is not even invariant basis number for free modules!

Comment: @Ben Regarding categories:  I suspected as much.  I just didn't want to go there.  Regarding rank-nullity: indeed, but that doesn't necessarily preclude some notion of rank-nullity with respect to, for example, the Krull dimension.  But I'm an analyst, so this is way over my pay grade. ;)

Comment: I don’t think the krull dimension works either. For instance, for a domain the krull dimension of an ideal (a kernel) is the same as the ring itself.

Comment: @Ben My point was not that I think that there *is* a generalization, only that I don't know enough of the theory in that branch of mathematics to rule it out.  The kernels and images of homomorphisms play a really important role in a lot of places (e.g. homological algebra), hence it seems reasonable (to an analyst) to *suspect* that there is some version of rank-nullity for objects more general than vector spaces (though the "obvious* rank-nullity itself clearly fails for a module).

Comment: I don't like to rule things out when I lack the background, but I think that I have been fairly careful in hedging. ;)